How to increase the allocated space for Linux Ubuntu
During the setup I accidentally chose not enough allocated storage for Linux and I want to increase it from 200 to 350GB of allocated space. I chose in setup to dual boot Linux. What should I do to increase it. Is there anyway for me to do it visually. Or do I have to use terminal.
And how do I combine logical drive volumes together as well.
